# After restart logstash sincedb is not cleaned (sincedb that generated in previous running)

Tags: logstash-file

I have an experience with the inode recycling problem, so I changed the sincedb_clean_after value like below.

```
sincedb_clean_after => "6 hour"
```

It is working fine.
But 6 hours after restarting the logstash, **the old record which is generated previous running is not cleaned.**
The record which generated current running is cleaned normally.

I think the logstash should clean old records in the sincedb no matter when they are created.

My logstash version is logstash-7.3.0

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug of logstash-input-file, and maybe fixed in 4.1.15.
https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/231